# How to calculate a correlation from a list of tuples - each tuple has pair values

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, statistics, correlation

I have a list of tuples which hold pair values in Python, for example:
[(0.2324,4),(0.8742,2), (0.11123,5)....]
I need to calculate the correlation between the paired values and the total correlation for this list.
I know about Scipy and Numpy, but I didn't find any function there to accommodate me.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Searched properly on `SO` - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnumpy%5D+correlation ?

Comment: Yes, saw most of them. but all of them talk about 2 arrays. I have 1 list of paired tuples. I wanted to know if there is a way of doing it without transforming the list of tuples into 2 arrays.

Comment: *"I wanted to know if there is a way of doing it without transforming the list of tuples into 2 arrays."* Why? That's a trivial one-liner. Any fast vectorized solution will require converting the data into an array at some point. You would have to do the whole thing with slow Python loops if you absolutely insist on using a list of tuples.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I already did unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

Hej there,

I ran into the same difficulties and ended up doing this:

```
from pyspark.mllib.stat import Statistics
x = result_rdd.map(lambda x: x[0])
y = result_rdd.map(lambda x: x[1])
Statistics.corr(x, y)
```

Not very efficient but it does the job.